# Beamer does not respect hyperref option

Tags: beamer, hyperref, color

I want to have an url colored in cyan in a beamer presentation. The following code is not working and produces a link in pink.

```
\documentclass[
xcolor = svgnames,
hyperref = {colorlinks = true, urlcolor = cyan},
]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Not the good color}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Meanwhile, passing the option through `hypersetup` works:

```
\documentclass[
xcolor = svgnames
]{beamer}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    urlcolor   = cyan,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The good color}
\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If relevant I am using pdflatex version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux).

Comment: To get the correct result, in your first code, remove spaces from `hyperref` options: `hyperref={colorlinks=true,urlcolor=cyan}`.

Comment: In fact, the only problematic space is the one after `hyperref =`. So you can use `hyperref ={colorlinks = true, urlcolor = cyan}`...

Comment: Oh my! And I thought I was being clever with spaces around the equal signs. I find it more readable that way.

Comment: keyval lists in documentclass options are not really supported, so they have some glitches. I would recommend to use \hypersetup for all options which can be set with it, and the hyperref option of beamer only for the ones which really need to be set when hyperref is loaded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the correct result, in the `hyperref` option of your first code, remove the space between `=` and `{`:

```
\documentclass[
xcolor = svgnames,
hyperref ={colorlinks = true, urlcolor = cyan},
]{beamer}
```